# Slack states that we haven't any space left but still uploads files

Tags: slack

We are on the free plan of Slack. This means, that we've 5 GB of space for files.

> Workspaces on Slack’s Free plan have a total of 5GB of file storage to
>   share. If you’ve reached the limit, files will remain accessible in
>   Slack but you won't be able to upload any more. You can delete shared
>   files to make room for new ones or upgrade to a paid plan.

As we hit the zenith, Slack started to send messages along the uploaded attachments:

> Your file was uploaded — it’s safe and sound in Slack. Unfortunately
>   your workspace doesn’t have any storage space left. To get more space,
>   you can upgrade to a paid account or delete some of your older files.

What does that mean? This warning is quite confusing. Does it mean we have unlimited space, but it's not guaranteed to last for an eternity? Does it mean older files get deleted to make room for the newly added file? Is it just a temporary thing and sooner or later we *really* aren't able to upload files anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slack's documentation says--
*Workspaces on Slack’s Free plan have a total of 5GB of file storage to share. If you’ve reached the limit, files will remain accessible in Slack but you won't be able to upload any more...*

But as you and I have experienced, it doesn't prevent you from uploading and doesn't prevent team members from retrieving the file. **Update:** It looks like some files that are uploaded beyond the limit **are disappearing from threads and the files panel within 24hrs of upload**, leaving only the warning message.

(My guess is that these over-limit files stick around as long as slack users are interacting with them, and eventually time out— becoming unavailable when left alone.)

This is probably Slack's way of not letting it's application become a speed bump for Workspaces.

Importantly, a file upload does count as another message, which causes the 10,000 message limit to come into play. A serious drawback here (that may cause some teams to buy Slack) is not being able to contextually find information by searching through conversations. When trying to find keywords in old conversations, users will meet the 10k limit warning which reads *"There's more to this conversation..."* paywall.

Source: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115002422943-Message-and-storage-limits-on-the-Free-plan#file-storage-limit

Comment: @pnuts Nope. Slack is a great service. From a business standpoint, teams who have more than 10k messages are incentivized to buy slack so they will regain the ability to search through their archives of every message ever —they also likely have the means to do so.

Comment: I've checked on my team. Photos are available even if they were uploaded two week ago.